# How to query column of CSV file stored in Azure blob storage using log analytics workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-dashboard

I have CSV file in Azure blob storage.i want to query this file using log analytics workspace to create dashboard .is it possible to create this.

Answer (score 0):

Using log analytics workspace, You cannot query data inside a file that is stored in the storage account.

Comment: Ok . But is there any other option to query data from storage account

Comment: You can achieve this by using any of this azure services Azure Functions, Azure Logic Apps, Azure Automation/PowerShell, Azure Web Apps.